# Infotech IS2525 Printer/MFP and Apple OSX 10.4

Tags: macos, printing, printer

Has anyone managed to use an Infotec ISC2525 printer/scanner from Apple OSX 10.4? I can't seem to get it connected and I'd appreciate some step-by-step advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Apple engineers must have sat around a conference table and thrashed out how they could make printing as difficult as possible for Windows users.

Despite my printer having AppleTalk and Bonjour protocols, both enabled, the Macs refuse to see the printer on the network.

In the end, I discovered I had to go into the Add Printer utility, then *hold down option while clicking the *More Printers* button*, then select Advanced, then and only then do I get the option for "Windows Printing via SAMBA".

Luckily, my printer supports SMB printing directly. Now I have the Mac talking to the printer, but its spitting out Postscript code instead of a printed page. Next problem: How to make a Max talk PCL instead of Postscript!

To solve that, I downloaded teh Gutenprint drivers. This package includes drivers for many Infotec printers, but rather frustratingly not the ISC 2525. So, I picked Generic PCL6 and that works fine, but doesn't understand some of the printer's finer features, such as its ability to print folded and stapled booklets!

But it's a solution... of sorts. Hope you find my adventures useful!